# How to define a distance between two strings based on how similar the characters look?

Tags: string, ocr, levenshtein-distance

I have a text extracted using an OCR and need to look for the sub-string most similar to a query string in it. I used the approach described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching). and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0196677480900164?via%3Dihub).
For two characters `a` and `b`, when using the distance defined as `d(a,b) = int(a!=b)` we have Levenshtein's distance. But in my case, some errors are more frequent than others because they come from the OCR. For example, **i** is more likely to be read as **1** than as **c**.
Is there any kind of measure that I could use to define a distance between two characters based on how similar they look (optically) ?